# How fresh are iostat data?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I am very confused about the output of `iostat`, it seems to me that the results of current disk usage such as mb/s written and read are very old or simply wrong.

I tried to copy 200GB file just to put some load on disk, in `dstat` I can see that there is 150MB/s being written to disk. When I run `iostat` the kb/s is still same as before I started writing to a disk.

Even after several minutes of copying, the iostat output still doesn't reflect any change.

Where does it get the metric from? How can I force it to refresh and display current data?

Answer (score 2):

After lots of googling, reading the manual page and trying I figured out following:

iostat by default outputs the statistics since system booted. That means for servers with high uptime these values will be pretty constant.

It is possible to display more fresh results by running

`iostat 1 2`

This will print the statistics since boot and then it will sample new statistics for last 1 second and print them, displaying real data for current time.

Answer (score 0):

I think `iostat` calculates global average usage, something like `kB_wrtn/uptime` or perhaps `kb_writn/(time_since_the_disk_appeared_for_the_first_time)`.
More than that, `kB_wrtn` may overflow eventually.

Run `iotop` to see current data.